# Does Javascript memoize Cache Between Imports?

Tags: javascript, lodash, memoization

Using the example below for [Lodash memoize](https://docs-lodash.com/v4/memoize/), my understanding is that `otherModule.js` will use the cached version fetched from `data` when fetching for `data2`, but will it also use the cached version for `data` within `otherModule2.js` if it was previously fetched/cached by `otherModule.js`? And if not is there a way to make it so the two modules share the same cache?

```js
// getData.js
import _ from 'lodash';
const dataPromise(url) = async fetch(url).then(value => value.json());
export const memDataPromise = _.memoize(dataPromise);

// otherModule.js
import { dataPromise } from './getData.js';
const data = await dataPromise('someUrl');
const data2 = await dataPromise('someUrl');

// OtherModule2.js
import { dataPromise } from './getData.js';
const data = await dataPromise('someUrl');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the top level of a module will run *exactly once*, no matter how many times it's imported. You'll see that if you, for example, put a `console.log` statement inside a module, that log will only occur once.

The first time a module is imported, a namespace object corresponding to the module is created, the module's top-level code runs, and the module's exports are assigned to that namespace. When the module is imported in the future, the already-existing namespace is simply referenced again.